# Why I Can't Run The Script Against Localhost?

Tags: 12.04, webserver

I have script which reads from `method` file :

```
OPTIONS
```

and checks whether the `OPTIONS` is allowed on a particular site. The script is :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
if [ ! $# == 1 ]
then
        echo "Usage: $0 [ URL ]"
        exit 1
fi

cat method | while read LINE
                do
                cat << __eof > header
$LINE / HTTP/1.1
Host:$1


__eof
nc $1 80 < header
done
```

So I can run this test against google.com and other sites. But when I run against `localhost:8080` I get an error :

```
nc: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

I'm very new to scripting. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a problem of scripting but your syntax at the nc command.

nc syntax is:
nc -l -p port [-options] [hostname] [port]
See man nc for further info.

When using the nc command, hostname is followed by port(s) separated by blank(s). If you call your script with parameter localhost:8080 the shell will not translate this so the port will be regarded as part of the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this add the following to your /etc/hosts, if it is not already there which is on most if not all ubuntu releases:

'127.0.0.1      localhost'

However I agree with Jens. It seems your syntax is incorrect. Yuu say you run it against localhost:8080 however in your script port 80 is hard coded, meaning you actualy say port 80 on host localhost:8080 and of course that host does not exist.

Kind regards,
Jochen